financial part of visitors visa
for my mum who is self-employed and does a local but successful business, how will she answer "How much do you earn from your business in 1 year, how much do you spend in 1 year for UK visitor's visa? please note: she will be responsible for her travel expenses

These are not trick questions nor should they be difficult to answer.

How much do you earn from your business in 1 year

Put the amount your mum pays herself from her business (often referred to as ‘drawings’) during the last 12 months.

how much do you spend in 1 year

Put the amount your mum spends on living expenses, like rent/energy/food, loan repayments, petrol, going out, clothes etc.
The figures you input will need to match the income/expenditure shown in your mum’s personal and business bank account statements.

Any other supporting documentation such as tax returns would also be helpful and would need to match both the answers to the first question and the bank account statements.

The visa form question is not "how much do you spend in 1 year", it is "How much money are you personally planning to spend on your visit to the UK?", which is what I think OP was asking about, you might want to update your answer. I put the cost of the first trip I'll make as I hadn't planned any further ones. (Separately there is also a "What is the total amount of money you spend each
month?" question, to which your answer applies, but it's a month, not a year.)

Also about exact supporting document recommendations, see here: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk

@ave I answered the question as asked. There’s also a huge number of related questions on this topic on TSE which the OP could have a look at. Just a guess but I think the OP’s underlying question is more likely to be ‘how does someone running a cash-based business demonstrate proof/provenance of funds’ rather than how to answer pretty straightforward questions in the application.

@Traveller ah I read "how much do you spend in 1 year for UK visitor's visa?"  as its "how much do you spend in 1 year for UK", when OP probably meant "how much do you spend in 1 year", you're right.
